# for loop skipping pixels in Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I am using a for loop to iterate over a jpg image. The image is shown below.

The image is of my timetable for this semester in college. As you can see, there are **green** cells, **yellow** cells, and **light brown** cells. I have the **RGB** values of each of these colors.

My task is to locate the first **green** or **yellow** or **light brown** pixel. Actually, I want to find out the top left corner of the first slot in the time table (**notice**: The first class on Monday, which in my case is green but would be yellow for an empty slot.)

[image]

Here is the python code I wrote to iterate over the image and find out the coordinates of the first point that is either green or yellow.

```
from PIL import Image
tt = Image.open("tt.jpg")
dim = tt.size
filled_slot = (203, 254, 51) #RGB values of green
empty_slot = ((255, 255, 203), (248, 239, 164))
             #RGB of yellow     RGB of light brown

start = [] #coordinates of the first pixel in the timetable

for i in range(dim[0]):
    for j in range(dim[1]):
       rgb = tt.getpixel((i,j))
       if rgb == filled_slot or rgb == empty_slot[0]:
           start = [i,j]
           break

print(start)
```

The image below is that of the timetable above with two circled regions: the **red circle** highlights the area where I expect the output coordinates to be, and the **blue circle** highlights the area where the program actually locates the coordinates to be.

My logic is that whenever a green or yellow pixel is located, where the iteration is being done column-wise, the loop should break and the point where it breaks is my output. The region circled red is where I expect the program to find the coordinates.

[image]

```
Expected output: around [117,101]
Obtained output: [982, 99]
```

**Why is it happening?** Am I getting the image iteration wrong or is it somehow getting **randomized**? What changes should I make to obtain the desired output??

Comment: Did you get the RGB values from some Image processing program or via PIL? It could be that you load your image and PIL translates to web colors, which would account for the randomization (your light yellow value is very close to a light yellow web color). For good measure, try converting your image after loading: `tt.convert('RGB')` and make sure the actual values are in the image. If the image only contains web safe colors you will not find your green value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only break the inner loop, but continue to search the columns. Best, write a function and return the result directly:

```
from PIL import Image
filled_slot = (203, 254, 51) #RGB values of green
empty_slot = ((255, 255, 203), (248, 239, 164))
             #RGB of yellow     RGB of light brown

def find_first_pixel(image, colors):
    dim = image.size
    for i in range(dim[0]):
        for j in range(dim[1]):
            rgb = image.getpixel((i,j))
            if rgb in colors:
                return [i,j]
    return None

tt = Image.open("tt.jpg")
print(find_first_pixel(tt, (filled_slot, empty_slot[0]))
```

Comment: This was definitely the problem. I'm used to using labels in Java and now that I'm picking up Python, I often end up making these silly mistakes. Thank you for understanding the flaw and suggesting a correction. (+1 for the idea of creating a separate function).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your data, not your code. Your iteration is correct (though as Daniel points out, inefficient) and Python is not randomizing your coordinates.

The colours are pixelated around the black digits. If you print out the colour of the pixels to the left and right of `start` you will see that they are `(251, 254, 207)` and `(255, 255, 201)`. Zoom in on the image at 600x or above and you will see there are yellowish pixels around the digits in the lilac and blue boxes.

You probably need to search for larger areas of the same colour, say a row of 5 pixels, before concluding the the colour indicates the box you want.

Comment: I agree with you on the fact that it would be better to consider some more pixels before concluding that I've reached the box I want. +1 for that.